# Do I have submit an actual binary in order to test In-App purchase?

Tags: iphone, submit, in-app-purchase

I have many versions released so far for an App (without In-App purchase).
Do I have to submit anything to be able to test In-App purchase?

What do I have to do?
I've implemented this - http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/ - so far, nothing happens when hit Product Details, or Purchase.

Comment: Or just "Ready to upload" state is more than enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to submit and reject a binary in order to advance your development process or test In-App Purchase. The link you're referring to, although helpful, is now out of date and the quirks in iTunes Connect that it refers to are gone, so don't follow it blindly!

The [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH1-SW1) is much more reliable and I recommend you use it instead. I actually wish I had started with the Apple docs rather than the link you provided when I implemented In-App Purchase in my app a few months ago--I can't recall the details but I do remember that it led me astray, particularly regarding the need to submit and reject a binary.

Answer (score 2):

No, there exists an In-App Purchase Sandbox. All you have to do is creating the App in iTunes Connect (under "Manage my applications") to add your In-App purchase items.